# python3 - Purpose of ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python-3.x, exception

I came across the new `ModuleNotFoundError` exception in Python 3.6 which seems to be a subclass of `ImportError`. The official documentation for [ImportError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ImportError) says:

> Raised when the import statement has trouble trying to load a module.

For [ModuleNotFoundError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ModuleNotFoundError):

> Raised by import when a module could not be located.

Was it really necessary to introduce an exception like `ModuleNotFoundError` ? What is it's purpose ? Also when would an `import` statement "have trouble loading a module" ?

Comment: A good place to start researching would be the corresponding issue: https://bugs.python.org/issue15767

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the answer; thanks to @Felix for giving a hint :)

Prior to Python 3.6, an `ImportError` was raised if a module, sub-package, class, function, etc was not found in an existing module. That means both `import foo` and `from os import ImaginaryClass` will give an `ImportError`.

In Python 3.6, a `ModuleNotFoundError` is raised only if the module does not exist and an `ImportError` is raised if the module exists, but the sub-package or class or function does not exist(or maybe for other reasons).

In Python 3.6 `import foo` will raise a `ModuleNotFoundError` and `from os import ImaginaryClass` will raise an `ImportError`.